# I am trying to get all the applications installed on all the devices using microsoft graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

I am trying to get all the applications installed on all the devices ios,ipad,iphone,android and windows devices using microsoft graph API.

my approach was first to get all the devices using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/manageddevices
and then passing each device id to
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/manageddevices('device_id')?$expand=detectedApps](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/manageddevices(%27device_id%27)?$expand=detectedApps)

but there are huge number of devices so the number of API calls i have to make is too many.

Is there any alternate way to do it .

Note:i tried https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/manageddevices?$expand=detectedApps
here but this seems to be not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`managedDevice` resource type doesn't have any relationship to `detectedApp` but `detectedApp` resource type has a relationship to `managedDevice`.

Make a first call to get all devices

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/manageddevices
```

You can reduce the size of the response by selecting only some properties you need

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/manageddevices?$select=id
```

Then the second call to get detected apps and expand `managedDevices`

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/detectedApps?$expand=managedDevices
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/detectedApps?$expand=managedDevices($select=id)
```

Group detected apps from the second call by managed device id and compare them with a list of all devices from the first call to find out which devices have apps.

Resources:

[List managed devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-list?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[List detected apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-detectedapp-list?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[detectedApp resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-devices-detectedapp?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships)

Comment: Thanks this is working is there a way I can get the device id's of devices that have the app installed as well from 2nd api call?

Comment: @user2250152 not in `1.0` nor in `beta` this no longer returns ids, it just returns an empty array of `managedDevices` :(

Comment: @zaitsman Could you please create a new question for this? I've quickly tried some requests and you are right. Looks like changes in API and these changes are not reflected in Graph API doc

Comment: @user2250152 Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77985019/get-all-detectedapp-managed-devices-out-of-intune

Comment: @user2250152 also raised by others, e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77591950/detectedappsexpand-manageddevicesselect-id-devicename-emailaddress-does-no