# /detectedApps?$expand=managedDevices($select=id,deviceName,emailAddress) does not return data in the expanded property

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

I'm trying to improve the speed of a script that runs through all my tenants trying to find a specific detected application.

On paper it should be possible to expand *managedDevices* on *detectedApps* to get a list of devices associated with the application.
I don't get an error returned and I tried both beta and 1.0. *managedDevices* is always empty.This is the case in various tenants I've tried both using API calls in Powershell and using Graph Explorer.

```
GET /deviceManagement/detectedApps?$filter=contains(displayName, '$($appDisplayName)')&$expand=managedDevices($select=id,deviceName,emailAddress)
```

Comment: Experiencing same :(

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't made any progress. Best I can tell its just broken.