# Get all detectedApp managed devices out of Intune

Tags: intune, microsoft-graph-intune

We have a requirement to provide a report of all `detectedApp` with not just a count but rather all individual devices they are detected on.

We tried

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/detectedApps?$expand=managedDevices($select=id)
```

Against both `v1.0` and `beta` but the response always contains `managedDevices` property as empty array:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#deviceManagement/detectedApps(managedDevices())",
    "@odata.count": 1,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "<SOME ID HERE>",
            "displayName": "MyAppName",
            "version": "1.1.0",
            "sizeInByte": 0,
            "deviceCount": 1,
            "publisher": "",
            "platform": "SOMEOS",
            "managedDevices": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Further, reading documentation on `$expand` that would be capped to 20 results only anyway.

Is there a way to get all `managedDevices` ids from **ALL** detected apps, not one by one?

When we do it one by one we keep hitting HTTP status code `429` for requests limits :(

**Update**

Using this request also returns an `empty array` under `detectedApps`

```
GET /beta/deviceManagement/manageddevices('<DEVICE_ID>')?$expand=detectedApps($select=id)
```